# Relationship between intransitives and transtives

Tags: logic

> 1. If I flew a bird, the bird flew.
> 2. If a bird didn’t flew, I didn’t flew the bird.

Is this English logic valid?

If I exemplify it,

A: my car broke.

B: who did break the car.

A: C broke the car.

Comment: These sentences don't make any sense to me.

Comment: @Dhanishtha Ghosh A: my car broke B: who broke a car A: C broke a car.

Comment: "the car" since A is specifying it is theirs

Comment: You cannot 'fly a bird' (unless you are practising [falconry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falconry). Your sentence 2 is ungrammatical; it has to be _didn't fly_. Also, a car _breaks down_ (develops a mechanical fault), a person doesn't break it.

Comment: "If a bird didn't fly..." not "If a bird didn't flew". Also "I didn't fly the bird..." not "I didn't flew the bird...". Usually one would say "I flew a plane", not "I flew a bird". "Who broke the car?" not "who did break the car".

Comment: @KateBunting I might say someone broke the car if the person operated it incorrectly and caused problems, like perhaps driving with the parking brake partially on.

Comment: @aschepler But not very idiomatically - I would say that person _caused damage to_ the car.